# Does testcafe support Web Workers?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-worker, testcafe

In my app I use a sdk for authentication purposes, which internally use a web worker to store credentials. I saw some git issues opened on this([Git issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2387), [Official site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqIBo.png)), in testcafe repo, and seems the feature is not yet supported.

Can I know exactly, whether this feature is supported or not in testcafe?

Answer (score 0):

In v1.10.1 and later, TestCafe fully supports Web Workers. If you face some issues with them, please describe them greater detail.